How to sum the number of rows which have duplicate data for only two columns in the data set combined? R language
I have two columns - index and reference which when combined are meant to make up a unique ID for a given row of data. I want to see if there any any duplications of these "unique ID's" or "unique combinations" without combining the two columns.
I thought about something like this within R:
sum(duplicated('Vehicles_Sub$accident_index && Vehicles_Sub$vehicles_reference'))

which gives me an answer of 0 but I'm not sure its correct.
Looked online for similar problems however I don't want to get rid of these duplications, I just want to count them or see if any exist.

What you did is not correct because 'Vehicles_Sub$accident_index && Vehicles_Sub$vehicles_reference' is a single string and therefore does not/cannot contain duplicate.

Hi @Laura, welcome to SO. It's always best to provide an example and expected output, e.g. with dput(head(data, 10)). That way you get relatively precise answers. For a little more guidance see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/9462095

Find a solution below
# count of duplicates
sum(duplicated(Vehicles_Sub[c("accident_index", "vehicles_reference")]))

# check if there is any duplicate: finds first duplicate if any
anyDuplicated(Vehicles_Sub[c("accident_index", "vehicles_reference")])


You could try the get_dupes() function from the {janitor} package:
library(janitor)
Vehicles_Sub |>
    get_dupes(accident_index, vehicles_reference)

